# Get terms present in a document with a collection

Tags: java, lucene, hashset, words, sublist

I'm developing a function to find terms into a document.
In parameter of my function, I give a `HashSet` of `String`. I browse the `HashSet` to analyze each string (with the Lucene Analyzer class) then I seek the analyzed string into the text with the `PhraseQuery` class to know if it exists into the document.
In return of my function, there is a `HashSet` which contains only terms found into the document.

It works, but slowly because of I browse all the `HashSet`. Is there no way to give a collection of words to Lucene, then get a collection with only the words that the document gets?

Comment: Wow! I was just asking almost exactly the same question: "Let's say I have 100 (possibly multi-word) strings and I want to ask Lucene which of these terms are present in a particular document. In other words, I want to get an intersection of query terms vs a document. Is it possible? Is it a valid use case for Lucene?"

Comment: I guess this question was already asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896183/get-matched-terms-from-lucene-query

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find this question ! It brought me to find this other good answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851473/lucene-get-matched-terms-in-query
Thanks again !